# Recursively calculate the sum of an Array of integers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, methods, numerical-methods

I wanted to write a JavaScript program to compute the sum of an array of integers **Recursively**.

> *Expected Results*
>
> > **Input**: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
> > **Output**: 21

I achieved the above results with this code:

```
function calculateSum(array) {
    if (array instanceof Array){
        if (!array.some(isNaN)) {
            var total = 0;

            array.forEach(function (value) {
                total += value;
            });

            return total;
        }
        return "Provide an Array with only Numeric Values";
    }

    return "Please provide an Array";
}
```

But I'm looking for a solution that uses *Recursion*.

**EDIT**: I started doing the above exercise to practice *Recursion*. I was having a hard time figuring that out. So, That's why I posted this. I'd be glad if you understood.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I want a solution that uses Recursion

Comment: Yes. Where are you stuck though? Asking to supply an entire solution is too broad. Show your attempt and ask a specific question regarding where you're stuck.

Comment: Why recursion when `.reduce()` can easily do what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use recursion you simply need a base case and way to spilt the input into something smaller you can recurse with.

The sum of an array of length 1 is just `arr[0]` right? So that's a plausible base case. With a larger array, the sum is one element plus the sum of all the others. So that's your other case: `arr[0] + sum(everything else)`

Now you can write a simple function with just those two cases:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 

function add(arr) {
    if (arr.length == 1) return arr[0] // base case
    return arr[0] + add(arr.slice(1))  // recurse
}
console.log(add(arr))
```

The idea is simple enough that you can express it as a one-liner:

```js
const add = (arr) =>  arr.length == 1 ?  arr[0] : arr[0] + add(arr.slice(1))
console.log(add([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] ))
```

Of course, you might want better error checking, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 3):

Destructuing syntax permits an elegant functional expression

```js
const None =
  Symbol ()

const sum = ([ n = None, ...rest ]) =>
  n === None
    ? 0
    : n + sum (rest)

console.log
  ( sum ([])               // 0
  , sum ([ 1 ])            // 1
  , sum ([ 1, 2 ])         // 3
  , sum ([ 1, 2, 3 ])      // 6
  , sum ([ 1, 2, 3, 4 ])   // 10
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

The recursion is actually a regression problem,
If the array named 'Arr' has only one element - this is the sum,
Now imagine you know the sum formula for an array of N elements,

You can now use recursion to find the sum of the (N+1) elements array since
it is simply the last element plus the sum of the previous N, which you already know/calculated.

An example is attached.
Read more at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion).

```js
let arr = [10,100,1000,10000];
function sum(array){
  if(array.length === 1){
    return array[0];
  }else{
    return array[array.length-1] + sum(array.slice(0,array.length-1));
  }
}

console.log(sum(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function add(arr) {
    if(arr.length>1) {
      arr[0] += arr.splice(1,1)[0];
      return add(arr);
    } else
      return arr[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this is a more beginner-friendly solution :) 

// 2. Compute the sum of an array of integers.



var sum = function (array) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var n = 0; n < array.length; n++) {
    // terminating case
    if (n === array.length - 1) {
      //   console.log('last', total, array[n]);
      total = total + array[n];
    } else {
      // recursive case
      //   console.log('befoer ', total, array[n]);
      total = total + array[n] + sum(array[n + 1]);
    }
  }
  return total;
};
sum([1,2,3,4,5,6]); // 21
```

Answer (score 0):

const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
//sum(array)  // return 21

```
function sum(array) {
    if (array.length == 1) {
        return array[0] // base case (exist condition)
    }
    else{
        return array[0] + sum(array.slice(1))  // recursion starts
    }

    
}
console.log(sum(array)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var numbers= [1,2,3,4,5,6];
sum=0;
function x(a,b){
  return a+b;
}
for (a in numbers){ 
 sum = x(numbers[a],sum);
 console.log(sum);
}
```

good luck

Answer (score -1):

```
    package Map;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Practice6 { 
        public int sum(int [] temp){
            if(temp.length>0) {
                int value = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                    value += temp[i];
                }
                return value;
            }return 0;
        }
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the array: ");
            int x= sc.nextInt();
            int [] data= new int[x];
            for(int m=0; m<data.length;m++){
                System.out.println("Enter the number "+m);
                data[m]= sc.nextInt();
            }
            Practice6 practice6= new Practice6();
            System.out.println(practice6.sum(data));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Write a function that finds the sum of an array. Make your function recursive.
sum([1, 2, 3, 4]) ➞ 10
working fine. Try it

Comment: This doesn't use recursion, isn't written in JavaScript, and doesn't demonstrate any best practices for the problem.